# Extremely slow graphical desktop startup process Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: lenovo, desktop-environments, 18.10, pam, xdg

I have experienced a stubborn issue after upgrading my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 18.10. Every time I would like to login into my system via lightdm the login process takes a lot of time (more than 2 minutes). This is definitely an issue because this process took about half minutes in my previous version of Ubuntu. The issues is affected both GNOME and XFCE.

I have tried resolve issues provided by journalctl but I did not found solution regarding most of those problem. I am sure this problem affects many users. I have been searching solution and also workaround such as install another desktop environment would be appreciated.

Some infos:

From journalctl the most suspicious issues:

```
febr 16 17:16:04 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 systemd[4236]: Failed to start Portal service.
febr 16 17:16:04 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 systemd[4236]: xdg-desktop-portal.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
febr 16 17:16:04 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 systemd[4236]: xdg-desktop-portal.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
febr 16 17:15:50 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 xdg-desktop-por[13570]: No skeleton to export
febr 16 17:15:50 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 xdg-desktop-por[13570]: Failed to create print proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk: Timeout was reached
febr 16 17:15:33 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=74:df:bf:3d:a3:f3:94:de:80:28:9b:f4:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.15 DST=192.168.0.19 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=18984 PROTO=UDP SPT=55672 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
febr 16 17:15:25 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 xdg-desktop-por[13570]: No skeleton to export
febr 16 17:15:25 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 xdg-desktop-por[13570]: Failed to create app chooser proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk: Timeout was reached
febr 16 17:15:24 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:28:9e:fc:04:ef:3c:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
febr 16 17:15:02 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=74:df:bf:3d:a3:f3:94:de:80:28:9b:f4:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.15 DST=192.168.0.19 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=18949 PROTO=UDP SPT=55661 DPT=8612 LEN=24 
febr 16 17:15:01 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 CRON[15003]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
febr 16 17:15:01 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 CRON[15007]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
febr 16 17:15:01 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 CRON[15003]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
febr 16 17:15:00 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 xdg-desktop-por[13570]: No skeleton to export
febr 16 17:15:00 premissa-Lenovo-Z50-75 xdg-desktop-por[13570]: Failed to create file chooser proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.gtk: Timeout was reached
```

I have looked for solution related to this issue, especially portal service but I have not found anything else only a lot of signalization of this problem.

Can anybody help to solve this issue? Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have completely reinstall the system, but this time I have chosen Lubuntu. The problem has been disappeared.

I am keeping this question opened because it seems the issue affects some users and there have been not any resolution yet.